# Buzz with Yamaha Silent Cello using Boss WL-50

Tags: amplifiers

I bought a Boss WL-50 wireless system to use with my Silent cello and am loving it! The only problem is that there is a high-pitched buzz. I tried fixing the problem by using [this adapter](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/GPP290--hosa-gpp-290-1-4-inch-trs-female-to-1-4-inch-ts-male-adapter), as suggested [here](http://forums.ernieball.com/ernie-ball-music-man-guitars/68042-mm-luke-iii-bfr-boss-wl-50-a.html) and [here](https://www.boss.info/global/support/by_product/wl-50/support_documents/eade711c-1f5a-4951-988b-e8e863611c64/), but that has only attenuated the buzz and not gotten rid of it completely.

Does anyone know how to fix the buzz?

Comment: have you tried plugging the instrument into the "input" on the boss unit using a regular cable to see if the high-pitched noise persists? This will bypass the transmitter. If the sound persists you might be able to eliminate the transmitter (and the TRS/TS grounding problem) as the source.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that my Yamaha Silent Cello also has a line out. Plugging the transmitter into that (and not the headphone jack as I was doing) solved the issue.

Probably different physical properties (impedance etc) for each output.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the receiver on battery or plugged in? I recommend the battery, to avoid pickup from the mains.

Next, look carefully at the output impedance and voltage of your cello (I am not sure all Yamaha Silent models are the same, or I'd tell you what I see on mine) and compare with the input impedance of the Boss transmitter, as well as its maximum input voltage.

If possible, test the Boss system with an electric guitar, since that's what the system was designed for.  If you still get a buzz, it's either

1. interference from some other 2.4GHz source such as WiFi , or
2. the whole WL-50 just stinks and you'll need to give up :-(